# Not able to refer to drawer layout in react native

Tags: react-native

I have my Js file like this.

```
"use strict"

var React = require('react-native')
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  Image,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
  Navigator,
  ListView,
  ToolbarAndroid
} = React;
var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');
var Drawer = require('react-native-drawer');
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen3';

class Screen1 extends Component {


 openDrawer(){
      this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer()
    }

    _handlePress(screen_name,loggedIn) {

      this.refs.DRAWER.closeDrawer(),

      this.refs.navigator.push(
        {id: screen_name,


      })

    }




  renderScene(route, navigator) {


  switch(route.id){
  case 'Screen1':   return (
DrawerLayoutAndroid
       drawerWidth={300}
       ref={'DRAWER'}
       drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
       renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
       <View style={styles.container}>
       <ToolbarAndroid
       navIcon={require('image!ic_menu_white')}

       titleColor="white"
       style={styles.toolbar}
       onIconClicked={() => this.openDrawer()}
       onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected} />
       </View>

    <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
         />
          </DrawerLayoutAndroid>


    );

     case 'Screen2': return (<Screen2 navigator={navigator} />)

     case 'Screen3': return (<Screen3 navigator={navigator}  />)
  }
  }

  render(){


    navigationView = (
              <View style={styles.header}>
              <View style={styles.HeadingContainer}>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback>
              <View style={styles.HeadingItem}>
              <Text style={styles.menuText}>
              Welcome!
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.menuText}>
              Guest
              </Text>
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 4, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback  onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this,'Screen1')}>
              <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.menu}>Albums</Text>
              <Image
              source={require('image!ic_menu_arrow')}
              style={{flex : 1,width: 10, height: 10, margin: 20}} />
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this,'Screen2')}>
              <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.menu}>Member Validation</Text>
              <Image
              source={require('image!ic_menu_arrow')}
              style={{flex : 1,width: 10, height: 10, margin: 20}} />
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this,'Screen3')}>
              <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.menu}>Settings</Text>
              <Image
              source={require('image!ic_menu_arrow')}
              style={{flex : 1,width: 10, height: 10, margin: 20}} />
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              </View>
              </View>
            );


    return(
    <
       <Navigator
       initialRoute={{id: 'Screen1'}}
       renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
       ref='navigator'
       configureScene={(route) => {
         if (route.sceneConfig) {
           return route.sceneConfig;
         }
         return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
       }} />

    );


  }



}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
  renderLoading: {

    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    alignItems: 'center'

  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
  },

  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  year: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
  },
  listView: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    margin:20
  },
  movie: {
    height: 150,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  titles: {
    fontSize: 10,
    marginBottom: 8,
    width: 90,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  menuContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  HeadingItem: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
  HeadingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#00a2ed',
  },
  menuText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'black',
  },

  menu: {
    flex: 4,
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'black',
    margin: 20,
  },
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#00a2ed',
    height: 56,
  },
});

export default Screen1;
```

Now I am not able to refer to Drawer reference variable 'DRAWER'.It gives me error undefined is not an object.Not able to open or close drawer.

I want DrawerLayout for Screen1 only so I am rendering it in RenderScene method.
If i implement DrawerLayout in render method,then I am able to refer to reference Drawer.

Can we create reference in render method only.IF yes how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing drawer object using state object of component.

```
"use strict"

var React = require('react-native')
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  Image,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
  Navigator,
  ListView,
  ToolbarAndroid
} = React;
var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');
var Drawer = require('react-native-drawer');
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen3';

class Screen1 extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                drawer: null,
        };
    }

    setDrawer = (drawer) => {
        this.setState({
            drawer
        });
    };

 openDrawer(){
      this.state.drawer.openDrawer()
    }

    _handlePress(screen_name,loggedIn) {

      this.state.drawer.closeDrawer(),

      this.refs.navigator.push(
        {id: screen_name,


      })

    }




  renderScene(route, navigator) {


  switch(route.id){
  case 'Screen1':
        const { drawer } = this.state;
     return (
        <DrawerLayoutAndroid
       drawerWidth={300}
       ref={(drawer) => { !this.state.drawer ? this.setDrawer(drawer) : null }}
       drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
       renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
       <View style={styles.container}>
       <ToolbarAndroid
       navIcon={require('image!ic_menu_white')}
       titleColor="white"
       style={styles.toolbar}
       onIconClicked={() => this.openDrawer()}
       onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected} />
       </View>

    <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
         />
          </DrawerLayoutAndroid>


    );

     case 'Screen2': return (<Screen2 navigator={navigator} />)

     case 'Screen3': return (<Screen3 navigator={navigator}  />)
  }
  }

  render(){


    navigationView = (
              <View style={styles.header}>
              <View style={styles.HeadingContainer}>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback>
              <View style={styles.HeadingItem}>
              <Text style={styles.menuText}>
              Welcome!
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.menuText}>
              Guest
              </Text>
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 4, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback  onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this,'Screen1')}>
              <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.menu}>Albums</Text>
              <Image
              source={require('image!ic_menu_arrow')}
              style={{flex : 1,width: 10, height: 10, margin: 20}} />
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this,'Screen2')}>
              <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.menu}>Member Validation</Text>
              <Image
              source={require('image!ic_menu_arrow')}
              style={{flex : 1,width: 10, height: 10, margin: 20}} />
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this,'Screen3')}>
              <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.menu}>Settings</Text>
              <Image
              source={require('image!ic_menu_arrow')}
              style={{flex : 1,width: 10, height: 10, margin: 20}} />
              </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              </View>
              </View>
            );


    return(
    <
       <Navigator
       initialRoute={{id: 'Screen1'}}
       renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
       ref='navigator'
       configureScene={(route) => {
         if (route.sceneConfig) {
           return route.sceneConfig;
         }
         return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
       }} />

    );


  }



}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
  renderLoading: {

    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    alignItems: 'center'

  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
  },

  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  year: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
  },
  listView: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    margin:20
  },
  movie: {
    height: 150,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  titles: {
    fontSize: 10,
    marginBottom: 8,
    width: 90,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  menuContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  HeadingItem: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
  HeadingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#00a2ed',
  },
  menuText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'black',
  },

  menu: {
    flex: 4,
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'black',
    margin: 20,
  },
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#00a2ed',
    height: 56,
  },
});

export default Screen1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy solution of your problem is make separate file for Navigating different scenes which contains only Navigator component, there you can navigate different scenes with suitable condition.

Make different files as:

```
  1. navigator.js
  2. screen1.js
 3. screen2.js
```

in navigator.js keep the code as

```
   <Navigator
   initialRoute={{id: 'Screen1'}}
   renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
   ref='navigator'
   configureScene={(route) => {
     if (route.sceneConfig) {
       return route.sceneConfig;
     }
     return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
   }} />
```

also do switch case statement here:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
switch(route.id){
case 'Screen1':   return (<Screen1 navigator={navigator}>
);
 case 'Screen2': return (<Screen2 navigator={navigator} />)
 case 'Screen3': return (<Screen3 navigator={navigator}  />)
 }
```

Then make individual component of screen1, screen2, screen3 and place all components like

```
      <DrawerLayout><Toolbar/><ListView/></DrawerLayout>
```

in which screen you want in their respective render() function, also you can call openDrawer() like function in your specific screen.

This way you can reduced your messy code organization and complete your code.

Hope this will help your problem.